# Как интерполировать полилинию в кривую

Tags: c++, математика, библиотеки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеку?

Обязательно сохранить исходные точки. Поясню, что дана именно 2D-полилиния, а не мат. функция. То есть, координата X последующей точки может быть меньше координаты X предыдущей точки.

Примерный интерфейс: на входе вектор с точками, точность(сколько соседних точек участвуют в расчетах); на выходе новый, "сглаженный" вектор.

Знает ли кто-нибудь такие библиотеки (желательно попроще) или функции?

Comment: Ранее пытался применить метод Лагранжа для функции, найденный [здесь](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/s/eb3c85c3d86dd40eb2b59ce7cd0ec9cc/topic-255254/anchor-entry2259801/0.html).
Но у него особенность: при большом кол-ве точек, появляется сильная амплитуда. Не подошло.
Есть похожее решение для сплайновой интерполяции?

Comment: Сплайн Акимы оказался наиболее подходящим.

Answer (score 5):

> Ранее пытался применить метод Лагранжа
> для функции, найденный здесь. Но у
> него особенность: при большом кол-ве
> точек, появляется сильная амплитуда.
> Не подошло. Есть похожее решение для
> сплайновой интерполяции?

При любой интерполяции при большом количестве точек будут "биения". Чтобы сгладить надо использовать аппроксимацию либо [методом наименьших квадратов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%E5%F2%EE%E4_%ED%E0%E8%EC%E5%ED%FC%F8%E8%F5_%EA%E2%E0%E4%F0%E0%F2%EE%E2) с заданным порядком полинома (пусть того же Лагранжа или Чебышева) или применить [метод Безье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130873/)

Comment: По ссылке нашел реализацию сплайна Акимы на PHP. Дело осталось за малым - конвертировать к c++ :)

Answer (score 2):

Ничто не мешает провернуть [сплайновую интерполяцию](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) для отдельных фрагментов полилинии - для метода spline interpolation нет ограничения на то, чтобы кривая была функцией.

---

В качестве доп. пищи для размышлений - гугл "smoothen polyline" и вот эти статьи:

- http://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~guha/papers/simpliPoly.pdf
- http://cipic.ucdavis.edu/education/CAGDNotes/Chaikins-Algorithm/Chaikins-Algorithm.html

Comment: Про разбиение на части не задумывался. После соединения сглаженных кусков, в местах стыка углы не образуются? Нужно обдумать.

Comment: > Ничто не мешает провернуть сплайновую интерполяцию

Если таким способом сглаживаются полилинии в 3ds max, rhino - то это как раз то, что надо. Не знаете?